# Monitor vs Watch on SourceForge Tracker

Tags: sourceforge

What exactly is the difference watching and monitoring a project on the SourceForge Tracker UI?

The tool tips aren't really helpful.

Hold your mouse over the "Monitor" button and it says "Monitor this project". Hold it over "Watch" and it says nothing.

> [image: sourceforge panel with buttons]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The "monitoring" and "watching" features are described on the SourceForge Wiki:

- [Activity watches](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Activity%20watches)
- [Monitoring](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Monitoring)

Monitoring gives you email alerts when things happen to a project (changes to Tracker bugs, posts in forums, etc.), whereas Watching customizes your SourceForge web page to show you projects/people you're interested in following.

If you're getting too much email, you can go to your "Account" page on SourceForge, and click "Monitoring" or "Watching", and see/adjust your settings from there.

An alternative to these features is to use RSS -- for example, on a project's File Downloads page, there are RSS links for each directory, so you can see in your RSS reader when new files show up for a project.